# How to use split on a string and then convert it to object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
let arr = ["a=1", "b=22", "c=11"];
```

And I want to split the string inside array so it becomes an object later, which will look like:

```
{a: 1, b: 22, c: 11}
```

Can I somehow do that

Comment: yes, you can definitely do that. Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string an map new objects. Later assign all objects to a single object.

```js
var array = ["a=1", "b=22", "c=11"],
    object = Object.assign(
        ...array.map(s => ((k, v) => ({ [k]: +v }))(...s.split('=')))
    );
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), so you wont be creating an array instead you will iterate through the array, and you can take each item and split so it will create an array
like item = ["a", "1"], you can assign the key as a to the object which is the first index and value is second index,The value is string so you can convert to number and return it.

```js
let arr = ["a=1", "b=22", "c=11"];

var obj = {}
arr.forEach(o => {
 var item = o.split("=");
 return obj[item[0]] = Number(item[1])
})

console.log("required obj", obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map` with `Object.assign()` to create your object. `string#split` each word on `=` and generate the object.

```js
let arr = ["a=1", "b=22", "c=11"],
    result = Object.assign(...arr.map(word => {
      let [key,value] = word.split('=');
      return {[key] : +value};
    }));
console.log(result);
```

You can also use `array#reduce`.

```js
let arr = ["a=1", "b=22", "c=11"],
    result = arr.reduce((r,word) => {
      let [key,value] = word.split('=');
      r[key] = +value;
      return r;
    }, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here, try this

```js
let arr = ["a=1", "b=22", "c=11"];

const obj = {}

arr.forEach(i => {
   const splitted = i.split('=')
   obj[splitted[0]] = splitted[1]
} )

console.log(obj)
```